# I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 1 in my native android project

Tags: android, firebase, admob, google-play-services

1) I connected my app to to firebase adMob correctly it is showing linked 
2) Verified my accounts for payments in admob panel
3) Added meta tag in manifest and all other code properly
Still it is not showing ads on the app any solution ?
Happy to add code if required.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't see ad after launching it in google-play? If it is your first app You should wait 2 or 3 days. When I launched my first app I was waiting 2 days to see ad in my app.

Comment: O Yes this is first first app with ads, will wait for 2 days. Thanks